# Call a function n times with an interval of n seconds

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I want to simply call a function 4 times within an interval of 10 seconds.
This calls it only once

```
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(myFunction()));
    timer->start(10000);
```

And if I get rid of the setSingleShot method, it will be called forever. Is there a built in way to call it only n times. I couldn't find it in the Qt documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brute-force, non-scalable way:  start four timers.

A more practical way is to have the callback keep track of how many times it has been called, then stop the timer on the fourth call.

Comment: Another (horrible) brute force approach: write a loop that runs four timed and calls the function followed by sleeping 10 seconds ;)

Comment: I was looking for an elegant built in solution, but I guess there's none. If I start four times then the function will be called four times after 10 seconds. What I want it to call it once after 10 sec, then again after another 10 sec ... and so on. I could use your second suggestion though. @Jesper Juhl I can't afford to sleep, I need to do other things. What's the best way to sleep in background?

Comment: @Gebre The four timers would have timeouts of 10, 20, 30, and 40 seconds, and was not a serious suggestion, just a bit of levity.  Having the callback destroy the timer after it has been called the proper number of times is the way to go.

Comment: Oh my bad, I misread it as four times. For the callback method, it means the timer has to be global, but I might go with that

Comment: @Gebre: the timer does not have to be global - you can pass the pointer to the timer to the callback with every call. If you go that route, you'd need to connect the timeout signal through a lambda.